# HOW to fix " Argument Z must be 2-dimensional"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to draw a 3d PLOT of my work ,but the error shows that Argument Z must be 2-dimensional

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
figure = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(figure)
X = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
Y = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
M=[]
for i in X:
 for j in Y:
  NEW_smoothed=holt(Airline_passengers,alpha=i,beta=j)
  M.append(sse(new_smoothed[:-2],Airline_passengers.values[2:]))
B=np.array(X)
N=np.array(Y)
Z=np.array(M)
ax.plot_surface(B,N,Z,rstride=1,cstride=1,cmap='rainbow')
plt.show()
```

I expected a 3d-plot

Comment: Check the type and shape of `X` and `Y` after `meshgrid`.  I don't think you need the extra `B` and `N` step.  What is the shape of `Z`?  Does it match `X`?  What does `plot_surface` expect?

Comment: M is a list and i wanna to have a Continuous graphics to show the relationship between X Y and Z.I think the error is i do not show the relationship between xy and z in that list

Comment: `X` is a (100,100) array, `Y` likewise.  `Z` should be the same.  A simple case would be `Z = X + Y`.  It needs to be a (100,100) array, with one value for each grid point defined by the `X` and `Y` grid.  I can't replicate your `M` calculation, but I suspect it has `len(M)` 10000.  `Z=np.array(M).reshape(X.shape)` might work.